# Rendering views with node.js + express + ejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs

I'm having difficulties rendering pages with ejs in my node.js app.

This is how I've set up the rendering:

```
    // index page
  app.get('/', function(req, res) {
      res.render('pages/index');
  });

  // team page
  app.get('/teams', (req, res) => {
    const teams = {
    nhl: data
  };
      res.render('pages/teams', teams);
  });

  app.get('/pages/team/:name', (req, res) => {

    const team = {
      nhl: data
    };

    res.render('pages/team', {
      name: [req.params.name],
      division: team.abbreviation,
      team
    });
  });
```

My index and teams pages are fine, just how they should be at the moment. Problem is that when I'm trying to render an own page for every team with some info, I cant get the info I want from api. In this case, I can get the name of the team right with this: `name: [req.params.name]` but for example the abbreviation gives me just `undefined`.
This is my team.ejs file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <% include ../partials/head %>
</head>

<body class="container">

  <header>
    <% include ../partials/header %>
  </header>

  <main>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-8">
        <div class="jumbotron">
          <h1><%= name %></h1>
          <p>Done using node.js + ejs template engine</p>
        </div>
      </div>



        <div>
       <h2></h2>

       <p><%= division %></p>
       <hr>
   </div>


    </div>
  </main>

  <footer>
    <% include ../partials/footer %>
  </footer>

</body>

</html>
```

This is the api what I'm using: https://statsapi.web.nhl.com/api/v1/teams

Comment: perhaps you need this  `division: team.nh1.abbreviation`

Comment: I've tried that, gives 'undefined' also.

Comment: How are you getting the data for every team using the API you provide?

Comment: You never defined `data` in your code?  Where is `data` coming from?

Comment: I've defined it in the beginning of my server.js:    `const nhl = 'https://statsapi.web.nhl.com/api/v1/teams/';    ` If I understood correctly what you asked.